# yhat Rodeo Dataframe viewer in version 2.0.13 does not show column with 0 name

Tags: rodeo

I just started using yhat Rodeo. on Mac OSX I cannot get the sorting of Dataframes to work like in the demo video.

Also "0" labeled columns dont show up in the DataFrame viewer but clearly are preserved in the  DataFrame.

for eg.

```
import pandas
df=pd.DataFrame({0:["dog","dolphin","chicken","ant","spider"],1:[4,0,2,6,8]})
```

Now going to the console . You see the entire DataFrame.

```
>>> df
         0  1
0      dog  4
1  dolphin  0
2  chicken  2
3      ant  6
4   spider  8
```

But the viewer does not show the "0" column or allow you to sort the "1" column.

Answer (score 2):

Member of the Rodeo team here.  This was a bug in <2.4.x, and is fixed as of 2.4.8:

`import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({0:["a","b","c","d"],"A":[1,2,3,4]})`

[image]